# how to force a line break in vtt for video

Tags: javascript, html5-video, vtt

I'm using the video track tag to insert captions and titles in my video. I have a vtt file, but I need a line break between lines 1 and 2. The text is showing up in the right spot, but on one line. How do I force a line break between the speaker and his title, please? A simple break in the vtt file doesn't do it.

vtt:

```
WEBVTT   This must be the first line followed by 2 returns

1
00:00.100 --> 00:04.999 position:0% align:left size:70%
JOE BLOW
survivor
```

HTML:

```
<div id="vid-container1" class="vid-container">

         <div class="speakers">  
          <div class="cap-wrap">
            <span id="room-speakers" class="display-speakers">
              <span></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <video id="video" poster="img/screen3.png" autoplay="autoplay" loop preload="metadata" muted playsinline>
            <source src="video/room.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>


            <track id="track-roomspeakers" default 
                    src="video/room-speakers.vtt" 
                    kind="metadata" 
                    srclang="en"
                    label="English Captions"/>


        </video>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
showTrack('track-roomspeakers', 'room-speakers');

    function showTrack(trackID, displayID) {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {  // don't run this until all DOM content is loaded
              var track = document.getElementById(trackID);
              track.addEventListener("cuechange", function () {
                var myTrack = this.track;             // track element is "this"
                var myCues = myTrack.activeCues;      // activeCues is an array of current cues.
                if (myCues.length > 0) {
                    console.log(displayID);
                  var disp = document.getElementById(displayID);
                  disp.style.display = "block";
                  var div = document.createElement('div')
                  for (var i = 0; i < myCues.length; i++) {
                    div.appendChild(myCues[i].getCueAsHTML());
                    //console.log(myCues[i]);
                  }
                  disp.replaceChild(div, disp.childNodes[1]);
                } else {
                  var disp = document.getElementById(displayID);
                  disp.style.display = "none";
                }

              }, false);
            }, false);

        var subtitles = document.getElementById(trackID);
        for (var i=0; i<video.textTracks.length; i++) {
          video.textTracks[i].mode='hidden';
        }
    }
```

css:

```
.display-speakers {
  font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.29);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.speakers {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: left;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
.cap-wrap {
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As James mentioned, I had to change my vtt file slightly to add an alert string, then later substitute a `<br>` for that string:

vtt:

```
WEBVTT   This must be the first line followed by 2 returns

1
00:00.100 --> 00:04.999 position:0% align:left size:70%
JOE BLOWtitlealert
survivor
```

javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {  // don't run this until all DOM content is loaded
              var track = document.getElementById(trackID);
              track.addEventListener("cuechange", function () {
                var myTrack = this.track;             // track element is "this"
                var myCues = myTrack.activeCues;      // activeCues is an array of current cues.
                if (myCues.length > 0) {

                  var disp = document.getElementById(displayID);
                  disp.style.display = "block";
                  var div = document.createElement('div');

                  for (var i = 0; i < myCues.length; i++) {
                    div.appendChild(myCues[i].getCueAsHTML());
                    var mystring = div.innerHTML;
                    if (mystring.indexOf("titlealert") >= 0) {
                        mystring = mystring.replace("titlealert","<br>");//make titles appear with name on one line, title on second line; only do this for speaker titles
                        div.innerHTML = mystring;
                    } 
                }

                 disp.replaceChild(div, disp.childNodes[1]);

                } else {
                  var disp = document.getElementById(displayID);
                  disp.style.display = "none";
                }

              }, false);
            }, false);
```

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer as it's just plain wrong and doesn't help you.  Another approach you might consider is to figure out the structure of the Document Fragment you get from getCueAsHTML, see if the artist/title are in separate elements and apply a class to one or both of them to get the visual you need.  Of course, it's possible that the doc frag has artist and title contained in the same element in which case your answer (text replacement) is the way to go!